# Google Analytics Hits sent but not visible on Analytics console

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have been trying to implement Google Analytics in my app by following the steps on the official documentation by Google. After completing the coding part, I moved on to the analytics console to see if I received any hits. I waited for almost 2 days but did not see any progress. I then tried to debug the problem by using GAv4 tag in my logcat. I got the following log,

```
07-14 11:11:22.734 31016-31016/com.dhinchek.user I/GAv4: Google Analytics 9.0.80 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                                           adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                                           adb logcat -s GAv4
07-14 11:11:22.760 31016-31016/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: setLocalDispatchPeriod (sec): 30
07-14 11:11:22.896 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Sending first hit to property: UA-77779576-2
07-14 11:11:22.898 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1468501882775, _s=0, _v=ma9.0.80, a=239605409, aid=com.dhinchek.user, an=Dhinchek, av=1.4, cd=Splash, cid=0a56ad2b-533b-4a48-84ef-285fbbb6a6f3, sc=start, sf=100.0, sr=720x1280, t=screenview, tid=UA-77779576-2, ul=en-us, v=1
07-14 11:11:22.907 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1468501882797, _s=1, _v=ma9.0.80, a=239605410, aid=com.dhinchek.user, an=Dhinchek, av=1.4, cd=Splash, cid=0a56ad2b-533b-4a48-84ef-285fbbb6a6f3, sf=100.0, sr=720x1280, t=screenview, tid=UA-77779576-2, ul=en-us, v=1
07-14 11:11:23.023 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
07-14 11:11:23.042 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
07-14 11:11:26.003 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1468501885946, _s=2, _v=ma9.0.80, a=239605411, aid=com.dhinchek.user, an=Dhinchek, av=1.4, cd=Login, cid=0a56ad2b-533b-4a48-84ef-285fbbb6a6f3, sf=100.0, sr=720x1280, t=screenview, tid=UA-77779576-2, ul=en-us, v=1
07-14 11:11:26.048 31016-31497/com.dhinchek.user D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

I am guessing if the hit is sent to the analytics service then the code is correct, but I am not able to see any progress in the analytics console. These two hits are for two different activities in my app. Can anyone help me out on how to further debug this issue, or suggest how to solve this problem? All views are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Is this running on an emulator without Google Play Services? If so, it's probably not sending them, so you may need to allow it to send with the local dispatch fallback.

Or maybe it hasn't been long enough? It only sends every 30 minutes by default, then takes the GA report site a few hours for it to show up anyway.

It may help to review the [official GA Dispatch docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch) that go into more detail and include other similar things you can try.

Comment: No, I am running the app on my device and it has Google play services. Could you tell me the debug messages that you get in your logcat, if you have an app with google analytics in it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a possible solution
I have tried with

> android version 8.1.104

and

> Google analytics version 11.0.2

and it works for me

Try updating the above plugin using sdk manager and for Google analytics update
specify the version in gradle file

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
}
```