# Google analytics for Android: Events are sent for delivery but not displayed in google console

Tags: android, events, google-analytics, tracking

I have Google Analytics(v4) integrated in my application. Everything is working fine **except event logging in the google console**, some events are being displayed but some not. In the debug information of the Hits , there is no error information and all the hits gets the same message that is

> D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery

I am making my event request as per the suggestion of GA, that is

```
AppInit application = (AppInit) context.getApplicationContext();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                                .setCategory("Create")
                                .setAction("CreateNewBinder")
                                .setLabel("Save")
                                .build());
```

Logcat for 3 different calls for GA events is as below:

> D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1472539419751, _s=22, _v=ma8.2.98,
>   a=1034701326, aid=com.**************.app, an=***************, av=4.1,
>   cd=***************HomeActivity,
>   cid=31855a2e-7905-4947-83bb-4ccd38447045, ea=CreateNewBinder,
>   ec=Create, el=Save, sr=1440x2392, t=event, tid=UA-44601745-10,
>   ul=en-gb, v=1
>
> D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1472539419767, _s=23, _v=ma8.2.98,
>   a=1034701326, aid=com.**************.app, an=***************, av=4.1,
>   cd=***************HomeActivity,
>   cid=31855a2e-7905-4947-83bb-4ccd38447045, ea=TransferQueueProcessing,
>   ec=Action, sr=1440x2392, t=event, tid=UA-44601745-10, ul=en-gb, v=1
>
> D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1472539419768, _s=24, _v=ma8.2.98,
>   a=1034701326, aid=com.**************.app, an=***************, av=4.1,
>   cd=***************HomeActivity,
>   cid=31855a2e-7905-4947-83bb-4ccd38447045, ea=TransferQueueOnSuccess,
>   ec=Action, sr=1440x2392, t=event, tid=UA-44601745-10, ul=en-gb, v=1
>
> D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery 
>   D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery 
>   D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery

Here the first event is not recorded but the last two events get recorded in the google console even though the debugger shows the same output for all the three requests.
 **I am at loss here that why the bottom 2 events gets recorded but not the first one**. Any help will be appreciated 
**Note :** My configurations are correct otherwise nothing should be displayed on Google console. Also i have waited for like 2-3 days in the hope that they may appear on the console but to no good.
Kinda same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375356/google-analytics-hits-sent-but-not-visible-on-analytics-console) but no answer was ever given